# Crystal Reports: Too many arguments given to this function

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011, winsql

I am new to crystal and still learning, I have the following formula field in crystal

```
IF ISNULL({command.Step1}) AND ISNULL({@step1 15 day check}) THEN ToText({command.step1Due}, 'MM/dd/yyyy') ELSE ToText({command.step1}, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

I keep running into error message that says "Too many arguments have been given to this function" I was curious if there was a work around.

Comment: To: `this function`, is which function?

Answer (score 0):

{command.step1Due} and/or {command.step1} are not DATE data type.

Because of that, the ToText() function doesn't know what to do with the date formatting argument.